# How to detect change in month in table calendar?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I want my table calendar to detect changes in a month, acc. to the swipe whether left or right. How to do that? and also is there any way to get the current visible month and year of the calendar after swipe.
How to do that?
and also is there any way to get the month and year on swipe.**

```
 TableCalendar(
                  focusedDay: selectedDay,
                  firstDay: DateTime(1990),
                  lastDay: DateTime(2050),
                  calendarFormat: format,
                  onFormatChanged: (CalendarFormat _format) {
                    setState(() {
                      format = _format;
                    });
                  },
                  startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
                  daysOfWeekVisible: true,

                  //Day Changed
                  onDaySelected: (DateTime selectDay, DateTime focusDay) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedDay = selectDay;
                      focusedDay = focusDay;
                    });
                  },
                  selectedDayPredicate: (DateTime date) {
                    return isSameDay(selectedDay, date);
                  },

                  eventLoader: _getEventsfromDay,
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (details) {
    int sensitivity = 8;
    // Swiping in right direction.
    if (details.delta.dx > sensitivity) {}
  
    // Swiping in left direction.
    if (details.delta.dx < -sensitivity) {}
  },
  child: TableCalendar(...),
)
```

Comment: this guesture isn't working.

Comment: on swiping my calendar this guesture isn't working, just working for some part.